# Is there any difference Value Type and Primitive Type, and Non Primitive Type and Reference Type. If yes then how all are different from each other

Tags: c#, .net, clr

C#: Is there any difference Value Type and Primitive Type, and Non Primitive Type and Reference Type. If yes then how all are different from each other.
I read it in C# documentation but it could clear my doubt about primitive and Non Primitive type.

Comment: What the CLR calls Primitive Types, the C# spec calls [Simple Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#835-simple-types), and they are a specific list of built-in types, which you can find by checking `typeof(SomeType).IsPrimitive`. Value types include them and all other `struct`s

Comment: @Charlieface: It's not quite that straightforward. `System.Decimal` isn't a primitive type, but it *is* a simple type.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hmmm, missed that, you're quite right

Comment: @JonSkeet Can't actually work out what `IsPrimitive` is supposed to represent, it seems to have no bearing on any part of the spec

Comment: @Charlieface: It's whether it's a primitive type *in the CLR* - it's not a language-specific concept. (Basically I'd expect it to mean "a value type that the CLR has dedicated operations for.")

Comment: @JonSkeet It does not appear to refer to anything in the CLR either, unless you can point me to a relevant part of [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf), because I cannot find it

Comment: @Charlieface: Sorry for not being clear. I'm not saying it's *defined* in the CLI spec - I'm saying it's related to what the CLR has direct support for. (I note that it's referred to quite a lot in the CLI spec, but without a definition.)

Answer (score 0):

The C# specification, [ECMA-334](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-334_5th_edition_december_2017.pdf), does not define the term *Primitive Type*. It does have the term *Simple Type*. There is also `Type.IsPrimitive` in the .Net Library.

The CLR (.Net) specification, [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-335_5th_edition_december_2010.pdf), also doesn't define it, but it does have *Built-In Types*, however they are not quite the same as simple types from C#.

> Weirdly enough, ECMA-335 does specify simple types, but only for custom attribute constructors, and corresponds to `Type.IsPrimitive`.

Value/reference types are somewhat orthogonal to that.

- **Value Type**
  This is a CLR (.Net) term, and is the same as a `struct` in C#. It is passed by value (copy/value semantics).
- **Reference Type**
  This is also a CLR term, and is the same as `class` in C#. It is passed by reference.
- **Simple Type**
  This is a C# term. It only includes `struct`s, and only the following are simple types:
  `sbyte` `byte` `short` `ushort` `int` `uint` `long` `ulong` `char` `float` `double` `bool` `decimal`.
  Note that `string` and `object` are *not* in this list, even though they have alias names in C#.
- [**`Type.IsPrimitive`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=net-6.0#remarks)
  This is the same list as above, except that it does not include `decimal`. It is unclear what it is supposed to represent in the specifications.
- **Built-in types**
  This is a CLR term, and refers to the same list as above, but also includes `object`, `string` (both of which are reference types) and `TypedReference`.

Comment: My guess for IsPrimitive is that it indicates which types are supported by the system ABI and are not pointers. It could also be types that fit in a register.

Comment: @siride Could be, although `string` `object` and `TypedReference` are also supported by the ABI. I admit they are all basically pointers though